# Jest typescript - The 'AsymmetricMatcher' is not assignable to type string

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs

I am new to jest and testing with typescript. I am having the above error in one of my test files. I searched a lot but couldn't find either the reason or the problem. I have other test files with the same value object `id:expect.any(String)` but they have no error.

Here are the sample files:

branchDetail.ts

```
    export interface BranchDetailsModel {
        id: string;
        brandId: string;
        name?: string;
        address?: string;
        employeeName?: string;
        position?: string;
        mobileNumber?: string;
    }
```

brand.spec.ts

```
...
const testBranchDetail: BranchDetailsModel = {
    id: expect.any(String), //Type 'AsymmetricMatcher' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    brandId: '',
    address: 'address',
    employeeName: 'sample',
    mobileNumber: 'sample',
    position: 'sample',
};
```

Comment: `testBranchDetail` is _not_ a `BranchDetailsModel`, because a matcher is indeed not a string. Presumably in the other places where you're using `expect.any` you're not trying to assign them to a variable with an incompatible type.

Comment: Yes. that helped me.